# Filter function with 2 array sets

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve the same result as i wrote in below syntax by implementing filter function to my script.

The current script i have

```
    let sheet = [
        { $0: { 'Name': 'Report1' } },
        { $0: { 'Name': 'Row Count' } },
        { $0: { 'Name': 'Report2' } },
        { $0: { 'Name': 'User' } }
    ]

    let nope = ['User','Row Count','Container']
    let result = []

    for(let i = 0; i < sheet.length ;i++){
        if(sheet[i].$0.Name != nope[0] && sheet[i].$0.Name != nope[1] && sheet[i].$0.Name != nope[2]){
            result.push(sheet[i])
        }
    }
    
    console.log(result)
```

On my browser inspect element, it will result of `(2) [{…}, {…}]` on console.log

I tried using filter function

```
    let result_2 = sheet.filter(w => !w.$0.Name.includes(nope[0]))
    console.log(result_2)
```

1 : One problem and logic i face is that im unsure on how can i includes all the element of 'nope' in 'includes()' 
2 : I will have to hard code the index such as nope[0] which i dont think is advisable if its going to be a big array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually almost finish but you reverse the `w.$0.Name` and `nope`.

```js
let sheet = [
    { $0: { Name: "Report1" } },
    { $0: { Name: "Row Count" } },
    { $0: { Name: "Report2" } },
    { $0: { Name: "User" } },
];

let nope = ["User", "Row Count", "Container"];

let result_2 = sheet.filter(w => !nope.includes(w.$0.Name));

console.log(result_2);
```

PS: I think you should take a break and drink some tea. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let result_2 = sheet.filter(w => !nope.includes(w.$0.Name))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and alternativr solution would be to use `every()` method within the `filter`. Like this:

It will check one element for every case of the second array and return true if nothing similar would be found.

```
 let result_2 = sheet.filter(w => nope.every(x=> x !== w.$0.Name))
    console.log(result_2)
```

```js
let sheet = [{
    $0: {
      'Name': 'Report1'
    }
  },
  {
    $0: {
      'Name': 'Row Count'
    }
  },
  {
    $0: {
      'Name': 'Report2'
    }
  },
  {
    $0: {
      'Name': 'User'
    }
  }
]

let nope = ['User', 'Row Count', 'Container']
let result = []


let result_2 = sheet.filter(w => nope.every(x => x !== w.$0.Name))
console.log(result_2)
```

Or if you want to use `includes()` you can do this:

```
let result_3 = sheet.filter(w => !nope.includes(w.$0.Name))
    console.log(result_2)
```

```js
let sheet = [{
    $0: {
      'Name': 'Report1'
    }
  },
  {
    $0: {
      'Name': 'Row Count'
    }
  },
  {
    $0: {
      'Name': 'Report2'
    }
  },
  {
    $0: {
      'Name': 'User'
    }
  }
]

let nope = ['User', 'Row Count', 'Container']
let result = []

let result_3 = sheet.filter(w => !nope.includes(w.$0.Name))
console.log(result_2)
```

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/82r36047/1/)